# Convert hover dropdown menu to clickable dropdown menu

Tags: html, css

Trying to change my navigation code from hover to click as I've realized there's no "hover" on mobile. I tried searching if there's such thing as :click in CSS, but closest I've found is :target, which doesn't do the same thing as clicking.
I'm just looking for advice for the most efficient way to change the code I have now to make it clickable.

```
.nav {
    position: sticky;
    left: 0;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.8);
    border-radius: 0px;
    border: none;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px 0;
    flex-direction: row;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.item {
    color: black;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    width: 25%;
    text-align: center;
}

.submenu {
    display: none;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: center;
    align-text: center;
    position: absolute;
    padding-top: 107px;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: small;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    z-index: 1;
    background-color: #2F4F4F;
    color: white;
    justify-content: left;
}

.submenu li {
    margin-left: 6%;
    width: 19%;
    padding: 5px;
}

.item.has-children:hover .submenu {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: left;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex: 1 1 calc(25% - 80px);
    color: black;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.8);
}
```

```
    <ul class="nav">
        <li class="item">
            <a href="index.html">
                <img src="../Images/Navigation/Intak Nav Mark -01.png" alt="Home"/>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="item has-children"><a href="Printing.html">Printing</a>

        </li>
        <li class="item has-children" style="color:#4D4D4D;">Graphic Design

        </li>
        <li class="item has-children">Chinese Calendars
            <ul class="submenu">
                <li><a href="Calendars/Cane Wallscroll Calendars.html">Cane Wallscroll Calendars</a></li>
                <li><a href="Calendars/Wall Calendars.html">Wall Calendars</a></li>
                <li><a href="Calendars/Mini Calendars.html">Mini Calendars</a></li>
                <li><a href="Calendars/Desk Calendars.html">Desk Calendars</a></li>
                <li><a href="Calendars/Special Desk Calendars.html">Special Desk Calendars</a></li>
                <li><a href="Calendars/Lucky Money Envelopes.html">Lucky Money Envelopes</a></li>
                <li><a href="Calendars/More.html">More Calendars</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="item"><a href="Contact Us.html">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: Can you use JavaScript or CSS only?

Comment: With your current markup its not possible to use CSS only.  You would need to add an input, then you could use input:checked as a selector.  Otherwise use JS to add/remove a class to the UL.

Comment: I don't mind adding javascript code, but I'm not familiar with it. If it's something someone can write up quickly, i'd appreciate that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this with using jQuery [change ".item.has-children:hover .submenu" with "submenuActive" and add js(jQuery) code]:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var countClick = 0; 
  $( "ul.nav li.has-children" ).click(function() {
    countClick = countClick + 1;
    if (countClick %2 == 0) {
      $(this).children('.submenu').addClass('submenuActive');
    } 
    else 
    { 
      $(this).children('.submenu').removeClass('submenuActive');
    } 
  });
  $( "ul.nav li.has-children" ).mouseleave(function() {
    countClick = 0;
    $(this).children('.submenu').removeClass('submenuActive');
  });
  
});
```

```css
.nav {
    position: sticky;
    left: 0;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.8);
    border-radius: 0px;
    border: none;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px 0;
    flex-direction: row;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.item {
    color: black;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    width: 25%;
    text-align: center;
}

.submenu {
    display: none;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: center;
    align-text: center;
    position: absolute;
    padding-top: 107px;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: small;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    z-index: 1;
    background-color: #2F4F4F;
    color: white;
    justify-content: left;
}

.submenu li {
    margin-left: 6%;
    width: 19%;
    padding: 5px;
}

.submenuActive {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: row; 
    justify-content: left;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex: 1 1 calc(25% - 80px);
    color: black;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.8);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav">
        <li class="item"> 
            <a href="index.html">
                <img src="../Images/Navigation/Intak Nav Mark -01.png" alt="Home"/>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="item has-children"><a href="Printing.html">Printing</a>

        </li>
        <li class="item has-children" style="color:#4D4D4D;">Graphic Design

        </li>
        <li class="item has-children">Chinese Calendars
            <ul class="submenu">
                <li><a href="Calendars/Cane Wallscroll Calendars.html">Cane Wallscroll Calendars</a></li>
                <li><a href="Calendars/Wall Calendars.html">Wall Calendars</a></li>
                <li><a href="Calendars/Mini Calendars.html">Mini Calendars</a></li>
                <li><a href="Calendars/Desk Calendars.html">Desk Calendars</a></li>
                <li><a href="Calendars/Special Desk Calendars.html">Special Desk Calendars</a></li>
                <li><a href="Calendars/Lucky Money Envelopes.html">Lucky Money Envelopes</a></li>
                <li><a href="Calendars/More.html">More Calendars</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="item"><a href="Contact Us.html">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: How do I make it that if they click on it a second time, it pops back up. I tried .click, but I think having two clicks cancel each other out. I tried .dblclick, that's what I'm using at the moment, but would rather one click. And do you know how to show that arrow key to notify it's a dropdown?

Comment: For arrow keys, you can use FontAwesome (https://fontawesome.com/icons/caret-down?style=solid). onClick you must change arrow key. For detecting second click, you can define a variable to count clicks: [step 1] define clickCount variable, [step 2] onclick: set clickCount=clickCount+1 (if clickCount%2==0 submenu addclass, else submenu remove class)

Comment: I tried my best to write the code, I've never written javascript, but it's sending me an error "unexpected token countClick"
Here's what I put together lol:
let countClick = 0

onclick = Set clickCount = clickCount + 1

if clickCount %2 == 0 {
 ('.submenu').addClass
}

else {
 ('.submenu').removeClass
}

Comment: I wasn't sure if that should go before or after the other javascript

Comment: countClick !=clickCount :) I have updated my answer

Comment: let clickCount = 0

onclick = Set clickCount = clickCount + 1

if clickCount %2 == 0 {
 ('.submenu').addClass
}

else {
 ('.submenu').removeClass
}
Here's what I'm hoping is the write code. Maybe my formatting is wrong? or {} positioned in the wrong place? Still same error "unexpected token clickCount"

Comment: LOL. I tried following your steps and making the javascript for it. It doesn't work, so I definitely botched it lol. Do you mind helping me write the javascript for the second click?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, CSS property "Active" is what you want to achieve?
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_active.asp

Comment: No that seems to just style a button or item that's clicked. 
I need to turn a hover drop down to a clickable drop down

Comment: https://codepen.io/whiteart/pen/dwgyn how about this? Change to mobile mode and check if it works for you. Unfortunately, I can't offer  solutions other than using JavaScript

Comment: I'm open to adding javascript. I'm just not familiar with javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for pseudo-clase CSS `:focus-within`
https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/:focus-within

Answer (score 0):

You can as well use JavaScript by:

```
`var all = document.querySelectorAll(".item.has-children");
all.forEach(function (e) {
    addEventListener('click', function (){
        e.classList.remove('submenu');
        e.classList.add('newMenu');
    })
})`
```

then change the `.item.has-children:hover .submenu` to a different class. In my case I used `newMenu`. Populate the `newMenu` class with your desired style.